# Windows Cert Management - How To

Tags: certificate, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I am supposed to fulfill a common-for-most-developers request to build/consume secure services using ssl/tls... via various communication protocols, not necessary wcf (web) services.

My problem is that I don't know much about certificates and I have been trying to get my background knowledge up to speed on the entire process.

The organization I am coordinating with issued 3 files for me to use:

AppName.cert.pem
AppName.csr
AppName.Key.pem

and also gave me a password for these.

The organization also gave me another certificate:

Organization.cert.pem

which is supposed to be used with their test tools.

The scenario is that the organization provided a test suite that runs on one vm, and the software I am building on another. I am supposed to import both of the certs into the vm with my software, and I think the organization's cert into the vm with the test software.

Problem is I don't know how, and the help links they provided are pointing to OpenSSL and some Java2SE tracing the secure requests/responses from either side....

Well, my code is written in C#, and both VM's use Windows Server 2008R2 x64 Standard/Enterprise. I am not sure how to import the certs, and configure them a) on a per application basis for a specific PORT and b) per domain basis?

Thanks,

Any help and guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I downloaded the OpenSSL windows client and converted the `AppName.cert.pem, AppName.csr AppName.Key.pem` into a single consolidated `AppName.PKCS12`.

I later imported the result using the Cert Manager (MMC Snap In) in each WS2008R2 VM environment and it worked just fine.

It turns out that the Cert Manager also does understand what is a `*.cert.pem` file so I was able to import the `Organization.cert.pem` as well on both VM's.

Thanks

PS: Never read instructions about Windows config written by a Linux/Unix nut-job. This whole exercise of certificate management would've been easier if the person that wrote the test software manual (which I ported from Linux by the way...) didn't send me on a wild goose chase due to his lack of understanding of the capabilities of the Windows Server Environment... No need for OpenSSL.

`<bleepzter/>`